# Axis2 generated Client to web service call - Unable to access unsupported property javax.xml.stream.supportDTD

Tags: apache-axis

I am getting the following exception when I access the web service from my Axis2 generated stub client.

Can anyone put some light one it?

Thanks.

```
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Unable to access unsupported property javax.xml.stream.supportDTD
        at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:123)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:67)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:354)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:417)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
        at amdocs.cl.utils.CollectionsServiceStub.GetEquipmentInfo(CollectionsServiceStub.java:267)
        at amdocs.cl.utils.DDPCollectionConnectorUtils.getEquipmentInfo(DDPCollectionConnectorUtils.java:162)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to access unsupported property javax.xml.stream.supportDTD
        at weblogic.xml.stax.ConfigurationContextBase.check(ConfigurationContextBase.java:60)
        at weblogic.xml.stax.ConfigurationContextBase.setProperty(ConfigurationContextBase.java:54)
        at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamInputFactory.setProperty(XMLStreamInputFactory.java:280)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.StAXDialectUtils.disallowDoctypeDecl(StAXDialectUtils.java:40)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.UnknownStAXDialect.disallowDoctypeDecl(UnknownStAXDialect.java:39)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXParserConfiguration$4.configure(StAXParserConfiguration.java:116)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils$7.run(StAXUtils.java:520)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.newXMLInputFactory(StAXUtils.java:495)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.getXMLInputFactory_perClassLoader(StAXUtils.java:566)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.getXMLInputFactory(StAXUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.getXMLInputFactory(StAXUtils.java:137)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.createXMLStreamReader(StAXUtils.java:196)
        at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java:64)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:197)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:145)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:108)
```

Comment: plz let me know if you have solved this. ty

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same issue and finally found that the problem is with incorrect context config. 
Axis2 configuration context is being created with weblogic.jar file instead of axis2 jar, so change the build class path order. First point all the axis2 jars and atlast point the weblogic.jar in class path.

Comment: Tried this approach as well, but issue not resolved. Can you please explain in much details ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding **jax-rt** jar in my classPath.

Or Add below dependency in your pom

```
<depepdency>
     <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
     <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.10</version>
</dependency>
```